How to route a subdomain to an IP
I tried this using haproxy in Ubuntu and CentOS but failed. I have an python app that needs IP to connect to the API but my current API is running on xyz.app.com and I tried asking the API owner for the IP but for security reason they won't provide it to me as its protected behind cloudflare.
Is there any way I can route a CentOS or Ubuntu server to the subdomain say xyz.app.com so my python app connects to the API.
Kindly do help if there is a way for this to work. I thought of using .htaccess to make this work but I doubt it will work.


I have an python app that needs IP to connect to the API

Sorry to say this, but your python app needs to be fixed. DNS was invented many decades ago, and DNS support is literally built-in to most HTTP clients – so make your python app use DNS. Requiring a fixed IP address for an API server is not reasonable in 2024, both from an administrative perspective (the API server's owner is free to move servers around and reassign their IP addresses), and from a security perspective – how does your app handle TLS? does it just disable the certificate validation?

Is there any way I can route a CentOS or Ubuntu server to the subdomain say xyz.app.com so my python app connects to the API.

HAProxy should be capable of this, although I don't have a configuration example. If it didn't work for you, then Apache httpd (or Nginx) would also allow this – in Apache you should define ProxyPass for the default VirtualHost (and very similar proxy_pass in Nginx).
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass https://xyz.app.com
</VirtualHost>

(I don't think you can use ProxyPass from within .htaccess, but it's a small step from editing .htaccess to editing the same kind of configuration in /etc/apache2.)

Should setup proxypass in Apache, the issue is when I use API which is behind cloudflare, it blocks every 20 request. Now I have no big business where normal users will come in and ask AI for Questions (different IP) and cloudflare will allow. Have 10-15 clients, 20-30 times, then cloudflare blocks IP of our server. Because client request xyz on our server > request the API URL. One option I have is redirect them to their subdomain API > results, but I don't want to reveal their URL or my clients will go to them. Hope you get my point.

Ah, basically you're trying to re-sell an API that you get for free?...

Kind of I sell AI services which uses OPENAI API, the script is designed to help you with just keywords typed only, and it will use AI to find similar code and code it for the user.
